# IE 11/XSLT/XML - BUG

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem that just started due to an IE 11 update.  Everything works in IE 9,10, FF, and Chrome.

I know it comes from the xml node (partdesc) value due to a space in the value (CSP 100-130).  I've tried using double quotes, I've tried replacing the single quotes to make sure they are the correct ones.  If I change the XML data to remove the space, IE 11 does not complain.  I've checked the space to make sure it is ascii 32 and I've tried to encode the xml various ways.  Nothing I've tried to this point works other than removing the space.

The exact unterminated string constant error (comes from IE Debugger)
**SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant

  File: SFCPacking, Line: 1, Column: 43**

The resulting HTML looks fine, but the click event will not work once the unterminated string constant error occurs.

Resulting HTML:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showCreate('98522000000000000000000','CSP 105-140','7500','4167','9595')"> - create ticket - </a>
```

I have XML data returned from a back-end that is transformed using the XSLT parser.  The parser does not throw any errors nor does the XML document reader.

Any help would really be appreciated!

The XML data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE XMLUtilResults>
<XMLUtilResults>
   <readonly>0</readonly>
   <canapprove>1</canapprove>
   <sfcsec>4</sfcsec>
   <srsec>4</srsec>
   <tsec>4</tsec>
   <view>Open</view>
   <packparts>
       <part recid="IDX985110000000000000000009595">
          <partno>98511000000000000000000</partno>
          <partdesc>CSP 100-130</partdesc>
          <availqty>3758</availqty>
          <onhand>3758</onhand>
          <invlocid>9595</invlocid>
          <invloc>0005</invloc>
          <invlocname>NACO Plant</invlocname>
          <qtypacked/>
          <sfcqty/>
          <opendemand/>
          <moq>7500</moq>
        </part>
     </packparts>
  <success>1</success>
  <OpenTickets>1</OpenTickets>
</XMLUtilResults>
```

The XSLT portion where the error occurs:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">showCreate('<xsl:value-of select="partno"/>','<xsl:value-of  select="partdesc"/>','<xsl:value-of select="moq"/>','<xsl:value-of select="availqty"/>','<xsl:value-of select="invlocid"/>')</xsl:attribute>
     - create ticket -
</a>
```

The JavaScript to transform the XML (XSLT)

```
var xml = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.3.0");
xml.async = false;
xml.setProperty("ProhibitDTD", false);
xml.load(xmlResp);

var xsl = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.FreeThreadedDomDocument.3.0");
xsl.async = false;
xsl.load(xslFile);

xsl_template = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate")
xsl_template.stylesheet = xsl;

xslProc = xsl_template.createProcessor()
xslProc.input = xml

if(paramObj){
    for(i=0;i<paramObj.pName.length;i++){
        xslProc.addParameter(paramObj.pName[i], paramObj.pValue[i])
    }
}

xslProc.transform()
document.getElementById(targetObj).innerHTML = xslProc.output
```

Comment: To update this, I was able to determine that IE11 and the XSLT transform is putting arbitrary line feeds in the data &#XA; and it's causing this error.  Now, how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/07/19/xmlhttprequest-responsexml-in-ie10-release-preview.aspx

And try using the `responseText` or set the `responseType` to `'msxml-document'` before sending the request..

Comment: Yea, did those too.  The responseText has the cr/lf in there also.  The msxml-document responseType as XML or HTML did not change anything.

Comment: @user3063475 Can you also try adding `xhttp.responseXML.preserveWhiteSpace = true;` before calling the `.send()` method ?

Comment: Yea did that too, it had no effect.

Comment: Gaby, we revisted the URL you mentioned and the responseType set to msxml-document did correct issue but essentially returning the responseXML as it did using the MSXML formats.  Using the older msxml activex object also wokrs which is essentially the same thing.  I still need to find out how to correctly transform the new responseXML using xslt.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes from the fact that Microsoft's new XMLHTTPRequest (as of IE10) is adding arbitrary cr\lf (\r\n) in the responseXML body when the original XML does not have the cr\lf.  This just started to happen in IE11 because IE11 does not seem to return True when checking window.ActiveXObject any longer.  Please note: our code to instantiate the object is as follows:

```
xhttp = (window.ActiveXObject) ? (new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")) : (new XMLHttpRequest())
```

The fix in IE10 was to continue to use the older Msxml2.XMLHTTP ActiveX Object, but since IE11 now returns false for window.ActiveXObject it was using the XMLHTTPRequest.

It's easy enough to change the code to a try and catch syntax, but the bigger issue is, once MS decides to get rid of the older ActiveX object, will the XMLHttpRequest object continue to add arbitrary cr\lf in the responseXML body.  This creates issues with the XSLT transformations.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ie = 0;
if (window.ActiveXObject || Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "ActiveXObject")) {
    ie = 1;
}
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = onReady;
xhr.open('get', '/test.xml', true);
if (ie) {
    try { xhr.responseType = 'msxml-document'; } catch(e){} // \r\n fix
}
xhr.send(null);
```